# Pandas - Comparison between different strings always returns True

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare the value in a cell of a Pandas dataframe with the cell immediately below it. To obtain the value from the row below the current row, I am using shift:

```
df['shift_minus_1'] = df['company'].shift(-1)
```

However, when I compare these values, Pandas returns True, even though some values are obviously not a match. Here is the code I am using for the comparison:

```
df['comparison'] = df['company'].shift(-1).values[0] == df['company'].values[0]
```

[image: Pandas comparison]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example...

Comment: Why are you falling back to `numpy`? Just use `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing just the first value in the array rather than the whole series:

```
df['comparison'] = df['company'].shift(-1) == df['company']
```

should work

What you did

```
df['comparison'] = df['company'].shift(-1).values[0] == df['company'].values[0]
```

is just comparing the first element in the array, this yields a single scalar value and so it sets the entire column to the same value

Example:

```
In[5]:
#data setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'company':['IBM','IBM','IBM','IBM','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple']})
df['shift'] = df['company'].shift(-1)
df

Out[5]: 
  company  shift
0     IBM    IBM
1     IBM    IBM
2     IBM    IBM
3     IBM  Apple
4   Apple  Apple
5   Apple  Apple
6   Apple  Apple
7   Apple    NaN

df['comparison'] = df['company'].shift(-1) == df['company']
df
Out[6]: 
  company  shift  comparison
0     IBM    IBM        True
1     IBM    IBM        True
2     IBM    IBM        True
3     IBM  Apple       False
4   Apple  Apple        True
5   Apple  Apple        True
6   Apple  Apple        True
7   Apple    NaN       False
```

Just to show what you did:

```
print(df['company'].shift(-1).values[0])
print(df['company'].values[0])
IBM
IBM
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `.values[0]`, which only selects a particular value (and hence, of course, always returns the same value).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['IBM', 'IBM', 'Apple'], columns=['company'])
df['shift_minus_1'] = df['company'].shift(-1)
df['comparison'] = df['company'].shift(-1) == df['company']
```

returns

```
Out[92]: 
  company shift_minus_1  comparison
0     IBM           IBM        True
1     IBM         Apple       False
2   Apple           NaN       False
```